# Why aren't Image and SpriteRenderer components inherited from one common base class?

Tags: unity-game-engine, inheritance, renderer

I'm righting a script that loads some sprites and want to use it on both UI and in the game.
But there are two types of renderers for each and without any common base class, although they both have Sprite in common!

I want to use both Image and SpriteRenderer, so i want to write sth like this:

```
class SpriteLoader<T> where T: SomeRendererBaseClass {
  T renderer;
    void Load(){
       renderer.sprite = GetSprite();
      }
}
```

but to use "renderer.sprite" i have to specify T, for which i found no common base class.

If i'm gonna show game characters in UI i should load sprites on Image component, but in the game, i have to do the same behaviour but on SpriteRenderer, and as programmers we don't like duplicate codes.

Comment: use an [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) instead

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If this is at design time you might be able to use PrefabUtility.ApplyPropertyOverride to get what you are looking for. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.ApplyPropertyOverride.html

Answer (score 1):

## Just because they both have a sprite doesn't mean anything.

You're going to just have to deal with the fact that the two classes aren't related to each other in the way that you'd like. This is no different than having a `Player` class that has a `name` property and trying to find a common parent class with `GameObject` ("it has a `name` too!")

The two classes have *nothing else in common* and should not inherit from some common ancestor (beyond whatever ancestor they do share).

Comment: Look, i have characters in the game that are rendered with SpriteRenderer. now if i want to show the user how to customize them, i'm gonna have a customize panel in UI (Canvas) in which characters are rendered with Image component.
I want to use the same behaviour on both renderers since they are basically the same, with different renderers.

Comment: @MhEskandari They're different renderer types, you need to treat them as different renderer types. Tough cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is to use the [Adapter pattern](http://www.ticktakashi.com/2015/12/unity-how-adapters-can-help-you-write.html).

```
public abstract class RendererAdapter
{
    public abstract Sprite spr { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ImageAdapter : RendererAdapter
{
    Image adaptee;
    public ImageAdapter(Image adaptee) { this.adaptee = adaptee; }

    public override Sprite spr  { get => adaptee.sprite; set => adaptee.sprite = value; }
}
```

```
public class SpriteRendererAdapter : RendererAdapter
{
    SpriteRenderer adaptee;
    public SpriteRendererAdapter(SpriteRenderer adaptee) { this.adaptee = adaptee; }

    public override Sprite spr  { get => adaptee.sprite; set => adaptee.sprite = value; }
}
```

To use it:

```
RendererAdapter thisRenderer;

private void Awake()
{
    if (GetComponent<Image>())
        thisRenderer = new ImageAdapter(GetComponent<Image>());
    else if (GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>())
        thisRenderer = new SpriteRendererAdapter(GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>());
    else
        Debug.LogError("error");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

At least they should have a common interface. I've seen that Unity API doesn't use interface at there best like .Net Does